# Evaluating stokes theorem $\int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ on the surface $z=4-y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, line-integrals

> Evaluate $\int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ o the surface $z=4-y^2$ cut off by $x=0$, $z=0$, and $y=x$.
>
> I particularly need help with evaluating the integral on $C_3$. Please see picture [image: here]

I am not too sure about the way I drew this, especially the part involving $C_3$. Anyway this is what I tried for $C_3$:

> $C_3$ is on the line $y=x$, I think, and we are told $z=4-y^2 \implies x=\sqrt{4-z}$. We note that $y=x$ on all point at line $C_3$
>
> $\therefore$ $\vec{r} =\left<x,y,z\right>=\left<\sqrt{4-z},0,z\right>$

Can someone please confirm whether that's the right parametrization and drawing for $C_3$ ? Any helpful suggestions are greatly welcomed and appreciated. -Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $y=x$ is not the equation of a line, it is the equation of a plane. The intersection of the surface $z=4-y^2$ with the plane surface $y=x$ is the set of points $$\vec{r} = (x,x,4-x^2).$$ This is the parametrization of the curve. The tangent vector is found by differentiating each coordinate, and we obtain $$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dx} = (1,1,-2x).$$ The limit for $x$ can be found by setting $z=0$ in the equation $z=4-x^2$. This is when $4-x^2=0$. Therefore $x=2$ and $x=-2$. The second point is thrown out because it is outside the bounded volume. Thus the parametrization is for $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

Comment: What would my limits on $x$ be for this parametrization i really don't see it changing: or do i need to use the limits on y?

Comment: @Ozwurld I don't see what limits you have written. It is not clear on the post. Regardless, to find the limit for $x$ you just need to find the solution for $4-x^2 =0$. This is when $x=2$ and $x=-2$. The second is discarded because it is outside the bounded volume.

Comment: am told that the actual image of the surface is like ![this][1] where would $c_1-c_3$ be on that curve how do i know which path to choose, please help -Thanks.

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TCPVH.jpg

Comment: @Ozwurld I don't understand your image. Regardless, the curve considered is the one contained in the plane $y=x$. This would mean the "lower" black-colored curve you've drawn.

Comment: I meant are the paths($c_1, c_2 \space to \space c_3$) chosen in the picture the right ones, do i always go anticlockwise and chose the outline of the curve from the front view![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ob6.jpg

Comment: @Ozwurld This is not a closed path, you aren't evaluating the paths $C_1$ and $C_2$ in your picture, only $C_3$. The resulting sign will depend if the vector field ${\mathbf F}$ is projected alongside your tangent vector $d {\mathbf r}$ or not. Otherwise, it doesn't matter. You can only define clockwise or counterclockwise for closed curves.